# phonegap index.js file why app.receivedEvent not this.receivedEvent

Tags: javascript, phonegap

Can anybody please tell me why in the following code `app.receivedEvent('deviceready')` is used, and not `this.receivedEvent('deviceready')`?

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments actually explain the reason for using `app` over `this`:

```
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent' 
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
```

Basically, the event handler will invoke the event callback with its own context of `this` (where `this` will be the event object).

The method `receivedEvent` is defined in app and not `this` (set to the event object inside an event callback function). To invoke `receivedEventil` in this case you would call it as a method on it's containing object `app`:

```
app.receivedEvent(...);
```

Comment: Well defined... Thanks @Pineda